# Django web app Docker - unable to connect

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new on Django and Docker and I have a problem to enter site localhost:8000.
I built django app and it is working on my local server but  I'd like to dockerize my app. So I created two files:
Dockerfile :

```
RUN python:3.6.7-alpine
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD ./ /code/
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

and docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python mysite/manage.py runserver 8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

My next steps:

```
docker built --tag django_docker:latest .
```

and:

```
docker run django_docker
```

It's open server, but when I want to open localhost:8000 from my browser I can't because of "Unable to connect"

Where is my fault?

More about django app : it's project from book Python Crash Course : Learning_log. I'd like to build an image and push it to hub docker, but I am stuck. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `docker-compose.yml` file, therefore you need to use the docker-compose command to run it:

```
docker-compose up
```

That's all you need, and you can read more about it in the official [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/).

To run it without using docker compose, then your docker command needs to be:

```
docker run --publish 8000:8000 django_docker
```

If you want to restrict the site to be available only on your localhost, then bind to `127.0.0.1`:

```
docker run --publish 127.0.0.1:8000:8000 django_docker
```

Answer (score 1):

## Try these

update dockerfile

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.7

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code

# Install dependencies
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system

# Copy project
COPY . /code/
```

update dockor-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

after updating just run one commands in terminal

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```

to stop it use

```
docker-compose down
```